# How can I update the date of a renamed folder in batch?

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, script, windows-backup

The problem is when I start the script it will copy the folder and rename it and add the current date and time to the name. But while the script is running and changes in the folder were made it would overwrites the old folder with the old date without the `/E /XC /XN /XO`.

So how can I let the script always copy the folder from source to destination and update the date so it won't get overwritten with the old folder?

Code:

```
@echo off
color 2

Set Source=C:\source
Set Destination=C:\destination
Set Folder=FolderName
Set currentdate=%date:/=-%_%time::=-%

robocopy "%Source%" "%Destination%\ %currentdate% %Folder%" /E /XC /XN /XO /mon:1 /mot:1
```

Comment: For starters, think hard about your destination part.  Do you really WANT a file named with a space at the front of it and a space between the date and "FolderName" ?  What exactly do you want to happen if there is already a target folder with that name?  Will that folder have files of the same name as the source and would be overwritten?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I'm running a dedicated game server and want to backup its save game folder. The folder will be overwritten when the server saves. So the script should make a copy of this save game folder after it was changed by the server (saved). The name of the backup should be the current date and the name of the save game folder.

So the backup should be made every couple minutes but the old backup should not get overwritten instead a new folder should be created with the current date so the names are not the same (no overwrite). But it doesn't work. dont think spaces are the problem

Comment: Edit: The space at the front should be removed of course but the is fine tuning it's not the problem.

Update:
robocopy "%Source%" "**%Destination%\%currentdate%** %Folder%"

Comment: You will need to write a loop.. check for the name.. if it exists, add a _1 to the end.. check again.. then a _2.. etc etc.loop until you find a unique name.  You can probably modify the logic from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802376/create-unique-file-name-windows-batch) but I wouldn't.  IMHO, it's too complicated for such a simple loop.

Comment: Would it not be possible to write an if function that refreshes the date and time when date and time is not similar to the date and time of the computer or any other way to just update the date and time?

Comment: Of course it is possible.  I was giving the case where there is already a folder with that name (which I think your question is based on).  I guess if you don't run it more than once a minute, that is not a problem.  I don't really understand what you want.  Please spell it out for me.